# Getting Black Screen while booting windows 7

Tags: windows-7

My system ( Desktop ) was working fine till yesterday , i have not installed or made any changes to it but this morning i suddenly getting a black screen with a blinking cursor

I tried pressing F8 so different booting options but only getting my hard disk as an option there, tried pressing CTRL + ALT + DELETE and CTRL + ALT + DEL and no success , also tried F5 to restore it but no success there aswell pressing f keys is just rebooting the system again and again

I have no idea what this is please need some urgent help

Comment: So many things can cause the black screen at boot, anything from bad hardware to a corrupted driver or malware, the list is too long. Start with hardware by removing non essential hardware from the motherboard and try booting.

Comment: What happens if you select your hard-drive from the boot menu? Can you hear your drive spinning up when you turn the system up? Does it make reading sounds? Do you see the Windows splash screen? Try pressing `ESC`, `F2`, `DEL` to access the POST and/or BIOS setup screens of the motherboard to see if the motherboard is working. In the POST screen (which enumerates your hardware) see if it displays your hard-drive. In the BIOS setup screen, find the section about drives and see if your drive is listed (don’t save any changes). (Also, `DELETE` and `DEL` are the same in pretty much every context.)

Answer (score 3):

The only times I have seen this (twice), the hard drive was broken and I had to get a new one and have my data transferred.

Answer (score 3):

Did you mess with your Boot files at all in the root of your C drive? Any new installs?

Can you get into safe mode? See if you can get there and run from the CMD prompt

```
sfc /scannow
```

Or boot from the Windows disc to see if you can get to the repair options.

Answer (score 0):

Try unplugging all the cables on the back including the power cable and then turn it on. This will drain the battery inside and then reconnect all the cables. This might reset any issues.

Comment: Its a Desktop system so the only battery inside could be CMOS one. Are you referring to that or am I missing something here?

Comment: It should drain the motherboard of any energy that it has making it reset and possibly resolve some errors